# Regex working in mongo but not using java

Tags: java, mongodb

This Regex is working in mongo query as below :

```
{$match : {'file_details.tec_stop' : {$regex : /(\d\|){1}\d/}}},
```

but now working when using java :

```
String stopRegex="/(\\d\\|){"+stops+"}\\d/";
pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("file_details.tec_stop'", new BasicDBObject("$regex", stopRegex))));
```

What's the issue?

Comment: You don't delimit a Java regex within a String using '/'. That would be redundant.

Comment: I'd also call `Pattern.quote(stops)` and use the result in `stopRegex`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the first `/` and the last `/` from your Java regex. They are Javascript specific regex literal which is the language used by mongodb shell

[Javascript RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Na it's still not working either.

I have a string like 1|0|2 and I am trying to match it with below reqular expression in java

^(\d\|){2}\d$

Comment: Because `|` is a special character in regex, you need to escape it first by prepending it with a backslash like `\|`, so to match `a digit|a digit|a digit` you need `^\\d\|\\d\|\\d$`